# Check if the value of one column contains the value of another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with java package names:

```
|id|pkg|
|1 |some.long.package.path|
|2 |com.admob.bla|
```

and a table that contains partial packages names form known advertisement frameworks.

```
|id|path_fragment|
|1 |.admob |
```

How can I retrieve packages whose value for pkg contains any of the ad_frameworks.path_fragment?

I just can't find the substring check. All I find is people using like to compare to some string literal but never for comparing columns.

NOTE: I am using MySQL.

Comment: check my answer below..it can be solved using `concat` and `like`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

think you could do an inner join with a like

```
select p.id, p.pkg
from package p
inner join ad_frameworks adf on p.pkg like CONCAT('%', adf.path_fragment, '%')
--group by p.id, p.pkg
```

or as you pointed

```
select * 
from package p
inner join ad_frameworks adf on LOCATE(adf.fragment, p.pkg) > 0
```

or

```
select * 
from package p
inner join ad_frameworks adf on INSTR( p.pkg,adf.fragment) > 0
```

or

```
select * 
from package p
inner join ad_frameworks adf on POSITION(adf.fragment IN p.pkg) > 0
```

or

```
select * 
from package p
inner join ad_frameworks adf on REPLACE(p.pkg, adf.fragemnt, '') <> p.pkg
```

Well, you've got few choices ;)

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d82/6)

Comment: Wouldn't that give me only those whoe pkg _ends_ with adf.path_fragment?

Comment: Academic question: Which one is the most performant of this possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    package a, ad_frameworks b
WHERE   a.pkg LIKE CONCAT('%',b.path_fragment,'%')
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8267/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT distinct a.pkg FROM TAB_1 as a INNER JOIN TAB_2 as b ON a.pkg LIKE CONCAT('%', b.path_fragment, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select p.id, pkg from packages p
inner join frameworks f on 
p.pkg like concat('%',f.path_fragment,'%')
```